# react-bootstrap/Carousel dimensions increase on slide animation

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

When the carousel does the sliding animation, the dimensions of the items grow to its normal size when the dimensions are supposed to be fixed to w-100.

I couldn't find any resources online that faced the same problems. This is for the react-bootstrap/Carousel library and it is a list item.

Any help would be appreciated!

```html
<ListItem>
  <Paper>
    <Carousel interval={false} activeIndex={index} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src="https://picsum.photos/200"
          alt={listing.address}
        />
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src="https://picsum.photos/200"
          alt={listing.address}
        />
      </Carousel.Item>
    </Carousel>
  </Paper>
</ListItem>;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try using `object-fit: cover;` property in your `img` `className` by making a CSS class

Comment: .carousel-item {
    object-fit: cover;
}

Doesn't seem to apply.. Same problem occurs

Comment: okay do one thing, post a gif or mp4 video using `peek` or some other tool, of what your'e getting and and image of what you are expecting, maybe then i will be able to help

Comment: can you create a `codepen` or `fiddle`, that way i can play and check why this is happening ?